# Covariance in and input-output filter [Stationary Stochastic Processes]

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, covariance, filters

> The weakly stationary processes $X_t$, $\;t=0$, $\,\pm$$1$,
>   $\,\pm$$2$,$\,\ldots$ and $Y_t$,$\;$ $t=0$, $\,\pm$$1$, $\,\pm$$2$,$\ldots$
>   are input and output of a linear filter according to
>
> $Y_t\;$$+\;0.5Y_{t-1}\;$$\;=\;$$X_t$, $\quad$ for $t=0$, $\,\pm$$1$,
>   $\,\pm$$2$,$\ldots$
>
> The process $X_t\,$ has the covariance function $r_X(0)=1$,$\,$
>   $r_X(\pm2)=0.2$,$\,$ and zero for all other values. Determine the
>   cross-covariance funtion
>
> $r_{X,Y}(\tau)=C[X_t,\,Y_{t+\tau}]$
>
> for all values of $\tau$.

I began by assigning the impulse function h(x) the following values:

$h(0) = 1\qquad$
$h(1) = 0.5$

Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The impulse response $h_{t}$ is actually given by $h_{t} = -0.5^{t}u_{t}$ (where $u_{t}$ is the step function). To obtain this, you can rearrange to get $Y_{t} = X_{t} - 0.5Y_{t - 1}$ and plug in values for $X_{t}$ being the discrete delta function, or you can take the $z$-transform to get the transfer function of $H\left(z\right) = \dfrac{1}{1 + 0.5z^{-1}}$ and use a [table of $z$-transform pairs](http://pfister.ee.duke.edu/courses/ece485/z_trans_table.pdf) to find the corresponding sequence. Either way yields the sequence $h_{0} = 1, h_{1} = -0.5, h_{2} = 0.25,$ etc.

We can then use the relation
$$r_{X, Y}\left(\tau\right) = \sum_{i = -\infty}^{\infty}h_{i}r_{X}\left(\tau - i\right)$$
which is found in several textbooks (eg. Probability and Stochastic Processes: A Friendly Introduction for Electrical and Computer Engineers by Yates and Goodman, Theorem 11.5) with the provided covariance function for $X_{t}$ to obtain
$$r_{X, Y}\left(\tau\right) = h_{\tau} + 0.2h_{\tau + 2} + 0.2h_{\tau - 2}$$

Comment: I really wanna thank you for your time and answer. Whilst I remember the step function very well from Automatic Control, I can't really recall it ever being discussed in my Stochastic Process class. Very strange.

Comment: The step function is really only used to address one subtle technicality (often overlooked), which is that the impulse response is zero for $t < 0$. Writing the impulse response using the step function is just an elegant way to express/acknowledge this.

Comment: I see. I basically came up with the values above by using the formula: $X(t) = \sum_{u = -\infty}^{\infty}h_{u}Y(t - u)$